# Share bitbucket pipeline image generated in default to parallel steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket with pipelines for Ruby On Rails application. My aim is to use the pipeline with parallel steps to run each of the Rspecs in the parallel pipeline. To do that I have added a default step to install the dependencies and then use the parallel steps to run each RSpec like models, controllers, etc, But on researching, it is found that pipelines execute in different containers, so we can't share this in parallel steps. Below are the changes I have done so far.

```
    image: ruby:2.5.7

pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
              name: Docker Build Image
              script:
                  - export DATABASE_URL=<test_db_url>
                  - apt-get update
                  - apt-get install libmagic-dev
                  - gem install bundler
                  - bundle config set without 'development'
                  - bundle install
                  - bundle exec rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
              services:
                  - redis
                  - postgres
        - parallel:
            - step:
                name: Model Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/models --format documentation
                services:
                  - redis
                  - postgres
            - step:
                name: Controller Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/controllers --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Helper Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/helpers --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Job Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/jobs --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Lib Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/lib --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Services Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/services --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Policy Specs
                script:
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/policies --format documentation

definitions:
    services:
        redis:
            image: redis
        postgres:
            image: postgres:9.5
            environment:
                POSTGRES_DB: pipelines
                POSTGRES_USER: test_user
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_user_password
```

But On executing, it is failed. Do we have a feature like once it is created a build that is generated from the default step, then we can share that build along with these parallel steps?.
I have tried using `artifacts`

Tried using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52676969/5023291

but running this causes with artifacts causes not working with the initial setup.

```
image: ruby:2.5.7

pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
              name: Docker Build Image
              script:
                  - export DATABASE_URL=<DB_URL>
                  - apt-get update
                  - apt-get install libmagic-dev
                  - gem install bundler
                  - bundle config set without 'development'
                  - bundle install
                  - bundle exec rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
                  - docker save --output test_dummy.tar test_dummy
              artifacts:
                  - test_dummy.tar
              services:
                  - redis
                  - postgres
                  - docker
        - parallel:
            - step:
                name: Model Specs
                script:
                    - docker load --input test_dummy.tar
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/models --format documentation
            - step:
                name: Controller Specs
                script:
                    - docker load --input test_dummy.tar
                    - bundle exec rspec spec/controllers --format documentation

definitions:
    services:
        redis:
            image: redis
        postgres:
            image: postgres:9.5
            environment:
                POSTGRES_DB: pipelines
                POSTGRES_USER: test_user
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_user_password
```

Please help me, if I am missing anything.

Comment: You could build a custom docker image, instead of a setup over the ruby image. Would that accomplish what you want to do?

Comment: so once a custom image is built with that, how we can share this build image over parallel steps, the outcome is to run the parallel steps to reduce the rpsec running time.